# Oops! Something Bad Happened to my user profile!

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Whenever I want to access my profile, be it on SO or SE (but not on meta.SO, SU, apple.SE,...), I get greeted with this nice screen:

[image]

Log out and in does not help. I can view other user profiles without problem.

Have I been a bad kitty? Do others have the same problem with their profile page or is it just me?

**Edit:** Ok, not all SO profiles work, check out some of the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) (not to mention that John Skeet's profile page works flawlessly).

**Seems to be fixed now.** Great job, that was quick!

Comment: We're aware of this and working on it...

Comment: I really want to know: If I keep clicking this link over and over and over, does it actually log the error every single time I click it[?](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/883279#883279)

Comment: "That's a nice profile you have there.  It'd be a shame if anything...bad...were to happen to it."

Comment: Happening to me also (also happening when i view some other user profiles but not all others)

Comment: Visiting all of the StackExchange websites during this "problem" is actually quite entertaining.  Is "Server Fault" using the cover to "Missile Command" to display the error?

Comment: I'm so sad you beat me, [my question clearly had more humor value](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123890/my-profile-page-throws-and-error-or-how-meta-stack-overflow-gave-the-ultimate-t) ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException: I'm sorry... here, you get an upvote (▲) :)

Comment: Presumably it only happens on profiles where the age is listed. Mine still works.

Comment: @mmyers: It goes without saying [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is the exception.

Comment: Yeah, mine works.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) did not take the community's advice around leap years and it's now Feb 29th in UTC land.

A fix will be pushed momentarily, but our love endures for the man.

Comment: That is hilarious.

Comment: I'd fire the guy that did that...oh, wait.

Comment: @LarsTech: Aha! Jeff claimed he was leaving voluntarily, but now you've uncovered the *real* story.

Comment: If SO had been launched like 5 months earlier, you'd have noticed that sooner...

Comment: Would it be possible learn about what the exact problem was?

Comment: @Felix `new DateTime(birthday.Year, now.Month, now.Day);`

Comment: And all of us had probably looked at that code over the years... a better solution is to get rid of Feb 29th :)

Comment: I vote for no more Feb 29th for the next 3 years!

Comment: Does this mean that the profile was broken *only* for those of us not born in leap years?  This bug is great for so many reasons.