# Profile page throws error (or how MSO learned to stop worrying and gave the ultimate tribute to the user "the Unhandled Exception")

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oops! Something Bad Happened to my user profile!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123888/oops-something-bad-happened-to-my-user-profile)

When I go to [my MSO profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131541/the-unhandled-exception) I see this **totally awesome and fitting tribute to myself:**

[image: YES!!!]

While I am *honored* that the SE team has decided that **the profile for "The Unhandled Exception" should display an error**, I was actually kinda curious about how many votes I had cast.

Can you give me *both* the really cool tribute error message *and* my actual profile page? K THX!

Comment: Also, this *is* happening on *every* user page I try to open. But that fact clearly reduces the humor value of my question :-(

Comment: `Bug report + joke + freehand arrow / exclamation == free EXP!`

Comment: Aww, maaan... `):`

Comment: @Rebecca Oh come on, this is clearly the superior bug report.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you forgot + Dr. Strangelove reference. **Something for everyone!**

Comment: At least i have a funny cat working on what appears to be an electronic version of Battleship when attempting to view my profile

Comment: @Michael: Needz moar meta.